# How can i show a blank option in jquery autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I am using a jquery autocomplete with combobox nabled. I want to show an empty option however whenever I set the value of my initial selection to an empty string it is not shown in the combobox.

The item is present it just contains no height.

Is it possible to have a blank option on an autocomplete combobox ?

Comment: have you tried appending a '<li></li>' to the top of the suggestion list after it gets the suggestions? you could insert it on the 'open' event.

Comment: This doesn't work becuase the combobox reduces the line height to nothing without some actual content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So we figured  out the solution. You need to work with the `_renderItem` method.

```
input.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    var listItem;
    if (item.label == "<strong></strong>") {
        listItem = $("<li></li>")
              .data("item.autocomplete", item)
              .append("<a><br></a>")
              .appendTo(ul);
    } else {
        listItem = $("<li></li>")
              .data("item.autocomplete", item)
              .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
              .appendTo(ul);
    }

    return listItem;
};
```

Take note that you must have a blank string item in your initial list for this to work.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, solved it like this:

```
$autocomplete.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $j( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append(item.label === '' ? '<a>&nbsp;</a>' : "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
        .appendTo(ul);
}
```

When item label is empty (`item.label === ''`) I just add a link containing a nonbreaking space (`&nbsp;`) instead of the label.

**EDIT:**

I realized this might introduce an XSS vulnerability. Make sure you escape the item label if it could contain user input. Either use some escape function, for example [underscore.js's escape function](http://underscorejs.org/#escape):

```
"<a>" + _.escape(item.label) + "</a>"
```

or build the anchor element using jQuery like this:

```
$('<a/>').text(item.label)
```

Comment: This worked for me.  However, I had to use `ui-autocomplete` for the data item.

Answer (score 6):

The two solutions posted here did not work for me. _renderItem is not even called for empty options.

Here is what worked for me: I made a very small edit to the function that maps Select options to autocomplete items.

```
response(select.children("option").map(function () {
var text = $(this).text();
if (/*this.value && */(!request.term || matcher.test(text)))
    return {
        label: text.replace(
            new RegExp(
                "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" +
                $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) +
                ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"
            ), "<strong>$1</strong>"),
        value: text,
        option: this
    };
}));
```

All what I did is commenting part of the condition.

```
/*this.value && */
```

Then I added to my stylesheet a rule for the autocomplete items.

```
.ui-autocomplete .ui-menu-item a
{
    min-height: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#ctrl").autocomplete({
    source: [ "\u00A0", "One", "Two" ]
});
```

Comment: I like this solution, very easy to setup. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue recently and while other solutions were mostly correct I found there was a step missing.

```
if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text)))
```

needs to be changed to

```
if (!request.term || matcher.test(text))
```

otherwise there will be no empty items in the source.

As with the other solutions, change _renderItem to

```
input.data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        return $('<li></li>')
            .data('item.autocomplete', item)
            .append(item.label === '<strong></strong>' ? '<a>&nbsp;</a>' : '<a>' + item.label + '</a>' )
            .appendTo(ul);
        }
```

This is a mix of BentOnCoding's and Tim Büthe's solution

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the autocomplete widget like this:

```
$.widget( "ui.autocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderMenu: function (ul, items) {
        var that = this;

        // add a blank item
        if (this.options.blankItem) {
            var blank = [{
                id: "",
                label: "<none>",
                value: ""
            }];
            items = blank.concat(items);
        }

        $.each(items, function (index, item) {
            var rendered = that._renderItemData(ul, item);

            // ensure min height on blank item. hmm, maybe a class would be better...
            if (index === 0 && that.options.blankItem) {
                $(rendered).find('div').css('minHeight', '30px');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And then use it like this:

```
$( "#textbox" ).autocomplete({
        source: contactNames,
        blankItem: true
    })
```

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/332476/) for that.

If you prefer not to extend the widget for some reason, you can add the function to the `change` method like this:

```
$( "#textbox" ).autocomplete({
    create: function(){
        $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderMenu = function( ul, items ) {
            [ _renderMenu function contents... ]
        }
    }
})
```